# Angularjs scope not update

Tags: angularjs

i try to set scope variables with geolocation lat and lon in this way:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);

var onSuccess = function(position) {
 console.log (position.coords.latitude);
 $scope.found.lat = position.coords.latitude;
 $scope.found.lng = position.coords.longitude;
};
```

Html i s very simple:

```
<div class="list">
    <div class="item item-body">
      <h2 class="rm-mr"><i class="ion-ios-location"></i>Your position</h2> 
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <p class="rm-mr">Lat. {{found.lat}}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <p class="rm-mr">Long. {{found.lng}}</p>
        </div>
      </div> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Console log works fine, but scope variables don't update. 
How can i solve that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post your html please =). Is the onSuccess function declared inside a controller?

Answer (score 2):

This function is probably being called out of a [digest loop](https://www.ng-book.com/p/The-Digest-Loop-and-apply/).

In that case, calling `$scope.$apply()` in the function will fix the problem.

```
var onSuccess = function(position) {
 console.log (position.coords.latitude);
 $scope.found.lat = position.coords.latitude;
 $scope.found.lng = position.coords.longitude;
 $scope.$apply() // <-- Starts a digest loop.
};
```